# display latest folders with latest snapdate using python & databrics

Tags: python, databricks

I want to extract the latest snapdate of blob folders and display storing into a dataframe.
I'm using Python and databricks.

```
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/product/1.0/fullsnap/2023-12-17/file1.avro
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/product/1.0/delta/2023-05-03/file1.avro
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/product/1.0/delta/2023-06-20/file1.avro
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/product/1.0/fullsnap/2023-12-17/file1.avro
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/product/1.0/fullsnap/2023-12-18/file1.avro
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/product/1.0/fullsnap/2023-12-19/file1.avro
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/catalog/1.0/fullsnap/2023-04-01/file1.parquet
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/catalog/1.0/fullsnap/2023-04-02/file1.parquet
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/catalog/1.0/delta/2023-12-17/file1.parquet
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/catalog/1.0/delta/2023-12-18/file1.parquet
mnt/customer-raw/olympus/catalog/1.0/delta/2023-12-19/file1.parquet
```

Output
[image]